# How debug a telegram bot in vscode using Node

Tags: node.js, telegram

I'm trying to debug a code that uses the telegram bot-api (written in node). 
But it runs ok until stops at this line :

`console.log('test')`

and does not execute anymore. the code works fine, the only problem its when i try to debug it.

```
const TelegramBot = require( `node-telegram-bot-api` )

const TOKEN = `BOT TOKEN`

const bot = new TelegramBot( TOKEN, { polling: true } )

console.log('test')

 bot.on('message', msg => {
    console.log("arrrived")
    console.log(msg)
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Olá ${msg.from.first_name}, welcome`)
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved.

first of all you have to add the following line:

````
...
bot.on('message', msg => {
    console.log("arrrived")
    debugger //line added```  
...
````

your settings.json must have this line:

```
"debug.node.autoAttach": "on"
```

then, in your bot ( on telegram chat) you send /start command.